# JFlex with CUP compile errors

Tags: java, jflex, cup

I am trying to run an example provided by CUP: [Parsing directly to XML](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projekte/cup/examples.php#xml).

I stored the 'Minijava Grammar' in a file named **minijava.cup** and the scanner into a file named **xml.flex**. I ran JFlex to obtain **Lexer.java** from the xml.flex file. After that I obtained **Parser.java** and **sym.java** after running the command specified on the CUP example:

```
java -jar java-cup-11b.jar -locations -interface -parser Parser -xmlactions minijava.cup
```

My directory looks like this:

```
input.xml
java-cup-11b.jar
java-cup-11b-runtime.jar
jflex-1.6.1.jar
Lexer.java
minyjava.cup
Parser.java
sym.java
xml.flex
```

I am trying to compile the Lexer.java file by using the following command:

```
javac -cp java-cup-11b-runtime.jar Lexer.java
```

but I get 47 errrors in the format "..cannot find symbol...". The first ones specify that classes sym and minijava.Constants can't be found.

> Lexer.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
>
> public class Lexer implements java_cup.runtime.Scanner, sym, minijava.Constants{
>
> ^   symbol: class sym
>
> Lexer.java:17: error: package minijava does not exist
>
> public class Lexer implements java_cup.runtime.Scanner, sym, minijava.Constants {
>
> ^ Lexer.java:679: error: cannot find symbol
>
> {return symbolFactory.newSymbol("EOF", EOF, new Location(yyline+ 1,yycolumn+1,yychar), new Location(yyline+1,yycolumn+1,yychar+1));

I do not understand why the sym.java file is not visible to Lexer or where to get the minijava.Constants file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the current directory (where your sources are) in the classpath. It is not included by default, but if you put `.` in the `%CLASSPATH%` (or `$CLASSPATH` for unices) environment variable.

Try to change the `-cp` setting to add the current directory `.`.

```
javac -cp .;java-cup-11b-runtime.jar Lexer.java
```

If you are on a GNU/Linux, OS X or any UNIX-like system, it would be

```
javac -cp .:java-cup-11b-runtime.jar Lexer.java
```

In the same way, add the current directory to the `-cp` parameter when running with `java` command.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I tried something similar previously: "javac -cp .*;java-cup-11b-runtime.jar Lexer.java", but didn't work. 

Now I get 15 errors that are related to the minijava.Constants, I will try to find where does that example expect me to get it from .

Comment: `.*` is not the same than `.`: the first one will search all files of the current directory which in my sense is wrong while `.` adds the current directory for searching the classes.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after you answered, I mixed the two in my head and taught each one did the other...

Comment: actually, I did a mistake: `.*` will not search all files of the current directory but rather all hidden files of the current directory (in unix-world), and I am not sure for Windows: it seems to look for `.` and `..` but I have not tested the effect.